# Any way to use the same ip for ingress and loadbalancer service?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gke-networking

I’m using GKE to host my project.

My project will serve some API via HTTPS, so I’m using ingress to route by path to services.

But my project also serve TCP connection with SSL handshake. Therefore I will need to use service of loadbalancer type.

However I only have 1 domain can be used. But ingress (http load balancer) requires global IP, and service (tcp load balancer) requires regional IP.

How can I serve both with the same IP?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Simply think about the usefulness of an IP. It routes the requests to the correct machine. If you have 2 types of machine (HTTP LB and TCP LB) you can't have the same IP because the traffic must be routed to different machines!

Answer (score 2):

Each service requires its own IP address.